# Do I need to use three javascript libaries for validation with ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to do validation of my form so I am looking at
the ASP.NET MVC4 sample application.

Here I see it uses the following:

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

Can someone explain. Do I need all of these js libraries. I 
thought I read some place that one was now doing the job of
the other but I see the sample still loads all three of them.

Comment: Yes you need to use these, if you require client side validation

Comment: No, he doesn't need all those scripts if he requires client side validation. That's a wrong statement, please read my answer to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain. Do I need all of these js libraries.

No, absolutely not.

For jquery unobtrusive validation you need the following 3 scripts added in that particular order:

1. `jquery.js`
2. `jquery.validate.js`
3. `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

The `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script has absolutely nothing to do with validation. This is used by all the `Ajax.*` helpers (such as `Ajax.BeginForm` and `Ajax.ActionLink`).

Now, this being said, ASP.NET MVC 4 uses script bundles. For example when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Internet Template in Visual Studio it will create the `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file for you containing the following registration:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

This means that out-of-the-box if inside your layout or view you call:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

you're gonna get in Debug mode:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

In Release mode (`<compilation debug="false">` in your web.config) all those scripts will be minified, compressed and bundled into a single script served through a dynamic endpoint.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you have any ideas why the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js comes as part of the sample application? I checked and don't see any use of Ajax.BeginForm or Ajax.ActionLink however I do see ajax.apply in jQuery.validate.

Comment: It comes as part of the sample application because Microsoft got sick of complaints from people saying for MVC3: `damn, my Ajax.BeginForm helper doesn't work. It doesn't send an AJAX request. Instead it replaces the entire contents of the page.`. The reason for this is because the person simply forgot to include this script.  So they decided to now include it out of the box. So if that very same person that was complaining in MVC3 now decides to use some of the Ajax.* helpers he wouldn't need to add this script. He wouldn't even know that this script is required. And I blame Microsoft for this

Comment: Now people won't even know what those scripts are nor why are they included in their default templates. Even worse: some script might get included in your website and you might never need to use it. Complete crap.

Comment: Thanks very much for your very clear explanation to this (and every other question I have seen you answer). Have a great day.